# Grab and plot 2D array's values crossed by a segment on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, scikit-image, subplot

**Goal**: Plot the values of a 2D array's cells crossed by a segment.

**How**: With Matplotlib, plot the 2D array (with `imshow`), grab the coordinates of 2 points defining the segment (with `plt.ginput()`), and input them in `line()` from `skimage.draw`. Then, plot the cells' values below the image of the 2D array.

**Problem**: The script works until plotting the cell's values, then it freezes without giving an error. I do not know how to solve this issue.

**Question**: how could I obtain the kind of plot like displayed on the figure below ? Where is the error in my code ?
[image: What I would like to get]

Here is my code with the bug. If you comment out the section as indicated, it will work but not as intended.

```
import time
from skimage.draw import line
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create array used for the plot
rough = np.random.randn(100,100)

# Function to give instructions in the plot
def tellme(s):
    print(s)
    a0.set_title(s, fontsize=16)
    plt.draw()

# Create a figure with 2 subplots: the image, and the plot of the transect's values
f, (a0, a1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1]})
a0.imshow(rough, vmax = 10)

# Allow 1 click-and-drag to zoom. If you don't want to zoom, simply click once
tellme('Zoom in an area if you want')
plt.waitforbuttonpress() 

# Select two points that will be the extremities of the transect
tellme('Select two points that will be the extremities of a transect')
while True:
    pts = []
    while len(pts) < 2:
        pts = np.asarray(plt.ginput(2, timeout=-1))
        if len(pts) < 2:
            tellme('Too few points, starting over')
            time.sleep(1)  # Wait a second
    
    tellme('Happy? Key click for yes, mouse click for no')
    
    if plt.waitforbuttonpress():
        break


# Allow a buffer before retrieving the array's cells crossed by the transect
plt.waitforbuttonpress() 
tellme('Please wait')

# Plot the transect
CS = a0.plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], color='red')


#### Leave this section to get the code that does not work. If you want the 
#### code that works, comment it out.

while True:

    # Convert the transect's extremities coordinates to integers in order to use the line() function
    pts = np.array(pts, dtype = int)
    # Retrieve the coordinates of the transect's extremities
    rr, cc = line(pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[1,0], pts[1,1])
    # Plot in the 2nd subplot the values of the cells crossed by the transect
    
    a1.plot(rough[rr,cc])
    a1.set_title('Values cells segment')

# Buffer before closing the figure
plt.waitforbuttonpress() 

plt.close()

####



#### De-comment this section to get the working script.

#plt.close()
## Convert the transect's extremities coordinates to integers in order to use the line() function
#pts = np.array(pts, dtype = int)
## Retrieve the coordinates of the transect's extremities
#rr, cc = line(pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[1,0], pts[1,1])
## Plot in the 2nd subplot the values of the cells crossed by the transect
#plt.figure()
#plt.plot(rough[rr,cc])

####
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then it freezes without giving an error

this is because your code is in an endless loop (the second `while True`)

Here is a working version with some tweaks (keep line end points visible during dialog, constrained layout, final title to press key to quit):

```
import time
from skimage.draw import line
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create array used for the plot
rough = np.random.randn(100,100)

# Function to give instructions in the plot
def tellme(s):
    print(s)
    a0.set_title(s, fontsize=16)
    plt.draw()

# Create a figure with 2 subplots: the image, and the plot of the transect's values
f, (a0, a1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1]}, layout='constrained')
a0.imshow(rough, vmax = 10)

# Allow 1 click-and-drag to zoom. If you don't want to zoom, simply click once
tellme('Zoom in an area if you want')
plt.waitforbuttonpress()

# Select two points that will be the extremities of the transect
tellme('Select two points that will be the extremities of a transect')
while True:
    pts = []
    if 'p' in locals():
       p.remove()
       plt.draw()
    while len(pts) < 2:
        pts = np.asarray(plt.ginput(2, timeout=-1))
        if len(pts) < 2:
            tellme('Too few points, starting over')
            time.sleep(1)  # Wait a second

    tellme('Happy? Key click for yes, mouse click for no')
    p, = a0.plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], 'r+')

    if plt.waitforbuttonpress():
        break

# Plot the transect
CS = a0.plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], color='red')

# Retrieve the coordinates of the transect's extremities
pts = pts.astype(int)
rr, cc = line(pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[1,0], pts[1,1])

# Plot in the 2nd subplot the values of the cells crossed by the transect
a1.plot(rough[rr,cc])
a1.set_title('Values cells segment')

# Buffer before closing the figure
tellme('Press any key to quit')
plt.waitforbuttonpress()

plt.close()
```